# How to set ControllerFactory for custom Nodes in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a general layout with some custom nodes, each with its own Controller. As I want to inject the same object into every of these Controllers, in order to share data between them, I create a custom ControllerFactory.

To set the ControllerFactory for the root node, I have the following working code in the start method of the Main (extends Application) class:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("layout.fxml"));
Main self = this;
loader.setControllerFactory((Class<?> param) -> {
        return self.instantiateController(param);
});
```

The instantiateController method in turn just creates a new of the passed class for the moment, and logs what kind of Class was instantiated:

```
public Object instantiateController(Class<?> c) {
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o = c.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    System.out.println(o.getClass() + " instantiated");
    return o;
}
```

This way, I can observed which Controllers were instantiated. It is always just the Controller of the root element, never of one of the custom nodes. Even though they get instatiated and are displayed as wanted, they never get factored by my factory. This way, I can not inject the object I want. How can I make the factory to be applied on all nested Controllers?

Comment: What do you mean "it is always just the controller of the root element, never one of the custom nodes"? The controller class is always defined in the root element.

Comment: How do you include the nested controls? Unless you use `<fx:include>` you create independent `FXMLLoader` instances not using the controller factory you use when loading `layout.fxml`.